# Command line autocomplete no longer escapes special characters on certain operations

Tags: command-line

When I'm specifying arguments to the `mv` or `cp` commands at the command line and I hit `tab` to autocomplete the argument, it lists the argument without special characters escaped. For instance, it lists `ajax-loader(1).gif` literally when it should list it as `ajax-loader\(1\).gif`

Autocompleted arguments to the `cd` command are listed correctly though. I don't know what's going on. I'd appreciate any help / insight.

Comment: Weird... ive tested it here (using `touch "ajax-loader(1).gif"` first), and autocomplete works correctly for both `mv` and `cp`. Are you sure you're in the right directory? Have you tested if `ls` autocomplete for that file is working fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check this out because I had the same problem and modifying /etc/bash_completion did solve it.

http://www.yenlo.nl/thijsvolders/2011/12/06/ubuntu-11-10-bash-autocompletion-changed/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @RolandiXor Noted and sorry, I'll do this next time.

Comment: You should do it this time as well. :)